Polar2Grid fails to produce geotiffs from NOAA-20 files
I'm using Polar2Grid v.3.1 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS to produce geotiffs from NOAA-20 data obtained from the CLASS archive as single-band h5 files (SVI01_j01_[..].h5, GIMGO_j01_[...].h5). I tested my installation with the data samples provided by CSPP and it worked with no issues.
The command:
$POLAR2GRID_HOME/bin/polar2grid.sh -r viirs_sdr -w geotiff -p i05 -f /home/..../SVI*.h5 /home/.../GI*.h5 -vvv 
Expected behavior:
Produce a two-band GeoTiff of VIIRS Band I05
Result:
An invalid, 0 byte Geotiff
The error message:

File "pyresample/ewa/_fornav.pyx", line 434, in pyresample.ewa._fornav.__pyx_fused_cpdef
TypeError: Function call with ambiguous argument types
/home/..../polar2grid_v_3_1/bin/polar2grid.sh: line 42: 10141 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python3 -m polar2grid.glue "$@" -vv

Could anyone advise what may be going wrong?
